# If $z^{3/2}$ is analytic then why its integral over a closed arc is nonzero?

Tags: complex-analysis

Writing $z^{3/2}$ as $e^{\frac32 (\ln r+i(\theta+2 \pi n))} $ and checking Cauchy-Riemann conditions $ru_r=v_{\theta}$ and $u_{\theta}=-rv_r$ it is analytic everywhere, but calculating $\int_C z^{3/2} dz$ on any closed counter does not leads to zero! Where do I do wrong?

Comment: The logarithm, hence this kind of root, has branches ...

Comment: It is not analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. This is a function which requires a branch. So it's possible the integral will not be zero if you take a contour around the origin.

Comment: @Mark, It *is* analytic in C. Its derivative is $\frac32 z^{1/2}$.

Comment: Your original statement is weird. If you write $z^{3/2}=\exp\frac{3}{2}(\ln r+i(\theta +2\pi n))$, it's stopped being a function since different choices of $n$ give different results. This is where "picking a branch" comes in, which can only be done on some domains, definitely not all of $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: $z^p$ is analytic everywhere iff $p\in \{0,1,2,\dots\}$

Comment: @Edi, it's not even continuous in $\mathbb{C}$, leave alone analytic. You need to use the argument to define a square root. Let's assume you take the branch $(-\pi,\pi)$. Well, how can you define it continuously on the negative real axis then? Above it the argument is very close to $\pi$, below it is very close to $-\pi$. So no chance. That function will be analytic after you choose a branch of argument, but you can't continuously define it in the whole $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @zhw., "A function f of 
the complex variable z is analytic at a point $z_0$ if it has a derivative at each point 
in some neighborhood of $z_0$". I don't see how this is related to branch when being analytic is a 'local' definition.

Comment: @Edi, but the function doesn't have a derivative everywhere. If something works on the real axis it doesn't mean it will work in the complex plane as well. To define this function you must choose a branch, otherwise it's not a function. But as I showed you the choose of branch will make the function discontinuous at some points, hence it can't be differentiable there.

Comment: @Mark, so if I choose the branch (−π,π) and evaluate $\int_C z^{3/2} dz$ for a circle of radius 1 centered at x=2 so integral will be zero?

Comment: @Edi, yes, by Cauchy's theorem it must be zero. Or even easier: the function has an antiderivative in the domain where it is analytic.

Comment: @Mark, I got it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $ Log $ isn't analytic in the hole plane. You have the following theorem:

Let $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{C} $ be simply connected and $ f \in H(\Omega) $. If $ f $ has no zero in $ \Omega $ then there is a $ g \in H(\Omega) $ with $ f(z) = e^{g(z)} $.

In your case $ f (z) = z^3 $ which has its zero at $ z = 0 $. Hence you have to choose $ \Omega = \mathbb{C} - \mathbb{R}_{\le 0} $ or something similar to define a holomorphic square root of $ f $ by $ \phi = e^{\frac{1}{2}g}$.